# Selenium grid to remote webdriver(chrome) hangs on get

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have a selenium grid with nodes on virtual machine. I can connect, open browser and close it but when i try navigating to a page it hangs on Executing: [get: http://google.com]

I use the latest verions of selenium, chromedriver and java.

Declaration:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities =  DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(@"http://xxx.xx.xx.xxx:6000/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

then i try to use it when i click a button on my win form:

```
 driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

I can see the node gets the command and logs Executing:[get:htttp://www.google.com] but just hangs. Url doesn't change in browser(its "data:," all the time )

I use windows 7 x64 and try to control browser on windows 7 x32. (if i connect to node on my pc the code works fine)

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am seeing the exact issue with Safari (python). I am using selenium standalone server v2.47.1. My current workaround is to use JS:

```
"driver.execute_script("window.location.href = '{0}';".format(url))"
```

I also observed that if you don't set a homepage on Safari or have it default to load the homepage on new tab/window, the webdriver acts up and hangs on 'get' method.